# How to remove .vimrc without sudo power

Tags: vimrc

My `.vimrc` is a directory and not a file, I don't remember doing an `mkdir` but oh well.

My problem is, I am on a school computer and don't have the rights to `rm -rf` the `.vimrc` file.

I am out of ideas. My original problem was that I got this error message when trying to open up something with Vim

> Cannot source a directory: "$HOME/.vimrc"

Comment: If you want to use vim without configuration, just do `vim --clean`. If you do want to add your own configuration, we can manage that without sudo; I just need to check the docs first.

Comment: Interesting. Anyhow, you should not need sudo rights, to remove a directory in your $HOME folder, just `rm -rf $HOME/.vimrc` should be enough, but perhaps just move it to some other space first, so that you can inspect the contents first: `mv $HOME/.vimrc $HOME/.vimrc.old`

Comment: Maybe could you try to add a _vimrc file. That alternative is used for Windows but could work for Linux too.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt normally your assumption would be true. But `.vimrc/` may, I don't know why but it may, be owned by root. And I don't think it's fair to imply OP didn't at least try `rm -rf` when they say they don't have the permission to do `rm -rf`.

Comment: @3N4N for deleting a file in myself owend directory, I do not need admin rights. Even if the file belongs to root. The thing that matters is: you need to have write permissions in the folder that contains the file you want to delete. (unless the folder has the sticky bit) That's why I said *should* However, if this fails, this may indicate a filesystem or hard-drive damage

Comment: `rmdir ~/.vimrc`? But given the rest I don't see why it would behave any differently.

Comment: You imply that you created the directory (have write permission to do so) but cannot remove it (do not have write permission to do so), which is strange.  What is the error message you get when trying to remove it?  Are you sure your $HOME environment variable is set properly?  How about cd to your home directory and just `rm -rvf .vimrc` from there?  Otherwise, you need `ls -ld $HOME` and `ls -ld $HOME/.vimrc` to see why it isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

**Problem** :

Can not start `vim` because of Directory `.vimrc` , which itself can not be Deleted.

**Solution** :

Override `.vimrc` with custom location by starting `vim` with `-u` or `-U` on the command line.

**Details** :

To override , start `vim` with `-u` or `-U` on the command line.

`vim -u myvimrc textfile`

You can put some Defaults in "$HOME/myvimrc" or it could even be EMPTY file.

You can consider some other Path , eg "$HOME/myvim/myvimrc" , in which case you should give that Path to `-u` too.

You can check more about `-u` or `-U` to tweak accordingly.

**Observation :**

You should contact the School IT Dept Admin to login to your Computer to Delete the Directory. Then you can make the Correct `.vimrc` file.

Answer (score 1):

You could try `vim -u /path/to/.newvimrc`, perhaps even add an alias for it in your shell to the standard `vim` command so you don't have to type the entire thing out, all the -u command does is specify an alternative .vimrc

To do so in bash/zsh add `alias vim="vim -u ~/.rcnew"` in your .bashrc or .zshrc somewhere and either restart your terminal or do `source .bashrc` for bash or `source .zshrc` for zsh

if you're on fish id recommend using an abreviation instead of an alias `abbr vim vim -u ~/.rcnew`, but if you want to use an alias instead add `alias vim="vim -u ~/.rcnew"` in your init.fish and then obv `source ~/.config/fish/init.fish`